# How to call back button in Action Tab

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Please help me.

I use `onOptionsItemSelected` to get to settings layout. There I activate `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled`

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem settings){
                    setContentView(R.layout.settings);
                    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(settings);
}
```

[image]

How can I get back to main layout from settings layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `onOptionsItemSelected` you need to find out whether the `MenuItem` that is clicked is your `Home` item.

I would use a `switch` like:

```
switch (settings.getItemId()) {
    // If home icon is clicked return to main Activity
    case android.R.id.home:
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
      intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
      startActivity(intent);
      break; 
}
```

Then I would either start the `MainActivity` again or just call `finish()` to end the current one. There is a very nice article with loads of samples which you might find useful here: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidActionBar/article.html